# Validation Rule for a Currency Field: Field not be blank and the value must be greater than 0

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I'm a administrator with basic knowledge on formulas for validation rules. I need a validation rule for a field (currency), this field must be greater or equal to zero and must be not blank. Can you help me with a formula? I tried some formulas, but did not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDITED

```
OR(
ISNULL(currencyField__c),
currencyField__c < 0
)
```

Comment: I tried:AND( ISNULL( currencyfield__c ) , 
currencyfield__c <= 0)

Comment: Edited my answer